# django.contrib.gis.db + Images

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I'm working on my first GeoDjango project. And I'm using [django-leaflet](https://github.com/makinacorpus/django-leaflet) + [GeoJSON](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/#module-django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson) together with leaflet-ajax to display markers on the map.

I would like to have an image attached to each "properties" to be displayed in the popup. But does **`django.contrib.gis.db`** play nice with **`ImageField`**. Because if I just go ahead and add a **`model.ImageField`** field to the model, I get an Type Error when saving from the Admin. That it has to be a string.

I just wanna ask if it is possible to do this? I'm hoping that is and that I've just made mistake, that I need to find. Or should take another approach?

P.S. I'm using Postgres

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem using `ImageField` with `django.contrib.gis.db`. Please post your code and the full traceback.

Comment: You are right. There isn't. I had I some garbage in the database. Sorry. Can you convert your comment to an answer, so I can close this? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem using `ImageField` with `django.contrib.gis.db`.